# Custom ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-widget, android-drawable, android-progressbar

I am trying to create a `ProgresBar` that looks like the following:

[image: Desired ProgressBar]

So far, I have created an object which extends ProgressBar, and now I am trying to figure out what my next step is.

I know that I need to override `onDraw()` with some logic that will decide how many squares to color in.  This is trivial.

What I don't know how to do is get these squares in the first place.  How can I replace the default drawable, so when I add my custom bar in the layout I can see something like my image?

Comment: all you need is to create a custom progress Drawable that reacts on level change, see Drawable.onLevelChange

Comment: @pskink are you saying that I don't need to use a progressbar?

Comment: yes, just extend Drawable and use setProgressDrawable

Comment: ok you need a ProgressBar but dont need to extend it, just use a custom Drawable

Comment: @pskink could you provide some code and then I will select that as the answer?

Comment: first extend Drawable and override draw() and onLevelChange() methods, in draw() just draw your rectangles based on current level, in onLevelChange() call invalidateSelf()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this custom Drawable:

```
class ProgressDrawable extends Drawable {
    private static final int NUM_RECTS = 10;
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    @Override
    protected boolean onLevelChange(int level) {
        invalidateSelf();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        int level = getLevel();
        Rect b = getBounds();
        float width = b.width();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RECTS; i++) {
            float left = width * i / NUM_RECTS;
            float right = left + 0.9f * width / NUM_RECTS;
            mPaint.setColor((i + 1) * 10000 / NUM_RECTS <= level? 0xff888888 : 0xffbbbbbb);
            canvas.drawRect(left, b.top, right, b.bottom, mPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
}
```

and test it with the following in onCreate:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

final ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
Drawable d = new ProgressDrawable();
pb.setProgressDrawable(d);
pb.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 0);
ll.addView(pb);

OnSeekBarChangeListener l = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        int newProgress = pb.getMax() * progress / seekBar.getMax();
        Log.d(TAG, "onProgressChanged " + newProgress);
        pb.setProgress(newProgress);
    }
};

int[] maxs = {4, 10, 60, 110};
for (int i = 0; i < maxs.length; i++) {
    SeekBar sb = new SeekBar(this);
    sb.setMax(maxs[i]);
    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(l);
    sb.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 0);
    ll.addView(sb);
}

setContentView(ll);
```