# Android custom horizontal progressbar with progress dividers

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-custom-view, android-progressbar, divider

I need to make a custom horizontal progressbar in Android, but it doesn't have to be continuous. It must have DIVIDERS for every progress value. For example: it must have green progress and white dividers.  Please see the next image to understand what I'm looking for. Thank you.

[image]

For now I am trying to make a custom Drawable and set it to the progress bar.

```
public class CustomProgressDrawable extends Drawable {

    private static final int DEFAULT_RECT_WIDHT = 20;
    private static int DEFAULT_RECT_COLOR;

    private int rectWidth;
    private int rectColor;

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public CustomProgressDrawable(Context context){
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context){
        DEFAULT_RECT_COLOR = context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black);
        rectColor = DEFAULT_RECT_COLOR;
        rectWidth = DEFAULT_RECT_WIDHT; // Default rect width
    }


    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

        float parentWidth = 300;
        float parentHeight = 40;
        float childTop = 0;
        float childBottom = parentHeight;


        for (int i = rectWidth; i < parentWidth; i  =+ rectWidth){
            paint.setColor(rectColor);

            canvas.drawRect(i - rectWidth + 10, childTop, i + 10, childBottom, paint);

        }   
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onLevelChange(int level) {

        invalidateSelf();

        return super.onLevelChange(level);

    } 
}
```

And in my may activity I have:

```
CustomProgressDrawable customProgressDrawable = new CustomProgressDrawable(this);

ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progressBar.setProgressDrawable(customProgressDrawable);
progressBar.setProgress(50);
```

Comment: create a custom Drawable class and use it in setProgressDrawable

Comment: And how would it be? Could you help me with that custom draeable class?

Comment: class DividerDrawable extends Drawable { ..., then override `draw` and `onLevelChange` methods

Comment: Do I have to draw all the rects and the dividers?

Comment: just rects, dividers will be drawn with the background

Comment: Qnd why do I have to Override onLevelChanged?

Comment: q: how can your Drawable know about the progress change and re-draw? a: by level change

Comment: I added some code of what I'm trying but it doesn't show anything. I don't really know what to do next ...

Comment: `invalidateSelf` in onLevelChange

Comment: Now I do invalidateSelf but nothing happens ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052063/custom-progressbar