# Custom progress bar with different height

Tags: android, android-view, android-progressbar

can anyone help me create a progress bar with a styling like this one:

[image]

I know this is a common question and solution can be found, but I didnt saw a progress bar with the progress heigher than the other part.

So can someone help me create this?

Comment: Create custom view, override onDraw and draw it yourself.

Comment: See these links 
http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/android-s-progress-bars.html AND
http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/custom-progress-bar-in-android.html

Comment: Here maybe the answer you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android

Comment: just call `setProgressDrawable` with your custom `Drawable` class instance, dont forget to override its `getIntrinsicHeight` method

Comment: @pskink can you give me an answer with a code exaple please..

Comment: @skywall can you give me a code example on how can i do that?

Comment: refer to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30873744/2252830 - it creates segmented progress bar but the idea is the same

Comment: @pskink I'll try this now and ill let you know

Comment: @pskink I've used your class, and now I have a question for you. How can i make the progress heigher than the progress bar? You said to override the `getIntrinsicHeight` method, right? What should I do there?

Comment: return your Drawable height there

Comment: @pskink can we chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87450/discussion-between-pskink-and-darko-petkovski).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So wih the help of @pskink's code, I've managed to create a solution for this issue. So here is the code and I hope it will help someone in the future!

```
public class ProgressDrawable extends Drawable {
    private final int mForeground;
    private final int mBackground;
    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    private final RectF mSegment = new RectF();

    public ProgressDrawable(int fgColor, int bgColor) {
        mForeground = fgColor;
        mBackground = bgColor;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onLevelChange(int level) {
        invalidateSelf();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        float level = getLevel() / 10000f;
        Rect b = getBounds();

        float gapWidth = b.height();
        float segmentWidth = b.width();
        mSegment.set(0, 0, segmentWidth * level, b.height());
        mPaint.setColor(mForeground);

        mSegment.set(0, b.height() / 3, segmentWidth, b.height() - (b.height() / 3));
        mPaint.setColor(mBackground);
        canvas.drawRect(mSegment.left, mSegment.top, mSegment.right, mSegment.bottom, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
Drawable d = new ProgressDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.toolbar_text_blue), getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.toolbar_text_blue));
                    dataProgress.setProgressDrawable(d);
                    dataProgress.setProgress(percent);
```