# How to make a custom SeekBar to show a color gradient in the bar?

Tags: android, seekbar, color-picker, android-seekbar, android-graphics

For learning purposes, I want to implement an HSV color picker like this:

[image]

I know that I'll be using `SeekBar`s, but how can I show those gradients in the bar of the `SeekBar`.

1. How do I show the 7 color spectrum in the bar, like the first one shown in the image?
2. How do I show the linear gradient from white to a specific color? And how do I show the linear gradient from black to a specific color?

I am not asking for code, just for rough outline of steps to go about it?

Comment: if you dont want exact code, then make a custom `Drawable` class and use it via `SeekBar#setProgressDrawable`

Comment: try this, you can find color-picker libraries here, [https://android-arsenal.com/tag/18](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/18)

Comment: @Naz141 As I mentioned, I am doing this for learning. So not looking for libraries.

Comment: @pskink I thought of that but the problem is that whatever color the user chooses in the first bar, the second and 3rd bar will have that color on one extreme side. For example in the given image the user has chosen orange in the first bar, so the right-side of the 2nd and 3rd bars is orange. So it is not as simple as creating an image in Photoshop and passing it to `setProgressDrawable`. =(

Comment: i dont mean any photoshop image,  i mean a custom Drawable **class**, a class extending  Drawable, something like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30873744/2252830

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SeekBar` indirectly extends `ProgressBar`, which has a method by the name of [`setProgressDrawable(Drawable d)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setProgressDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29), to draw that bar as the `Drawable` you pass into it as its argument.

You will have to implement your own custom `ShapeDrawable` (probably a `RectShape`) to give the gradient you want. See the [Android Graphics and Drawables guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#drawables) and classes around [Shader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Shader.html), e.g. [LinearGradient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient.html).