# Create multi range seekbar android with diffrent colors

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I want to create multi range seek bar like this:
[image: pic]

I see here   [custom seekbar with multi color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50061970/custom-seekbar-with-multi-color)  but the answer was confusing.

Comment: go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50061970/custom-seekbar-with-multi-color

Comment: Where you want to use this seekbar and how many seek pointers you want in the seekbar? Please explain your question little bit more and please show what you have tried??? Welcome the stack overflow !

Comment: i think a little search can be enough, is not it?