# How to divide a round progressbar into sections using xml or code?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-progressbar

I have my custom progressbar created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:thickness="10dp"
        android:useLevel="false">

        <solid android:color="@color/lightGrey" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:toDegrees="270">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="10dp"
            android:useLevel="false">

            <gradient
                android:angle="0"
                android:startColor="@color/grey"
                android:endColor="@color/red"
                android:type="sweep"
                android:useLevel="false" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

so the result is:

[image: now]

but I want to divide it in sections like this:

[image: requested result]

how can I do this using xml or drawing using canvas? I have to put sections in certain points

Comment: `Canvas#drawArc()`

Comment: @pskink can you provide some code please?

Comment: whats unclear after reading the official documentation?

Comment: I have never used canvas

Comment: ok, so what parameters passed to `Canvas#drawArc` you dont understand quite well?

Comment: I don't know where to put it, I simply want to put the dividers there, even statically. Dividers is just for graphical layout

Comment: if you want to do that `"statically"` then simply use static image with those dividers

Comment: I'll try but I would prefer to do that via code

Comment: Turri using canvas you drawing you will ger idea from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30873744/5995648),
actually this link for horizontal progress bar but  i am sure you will get idea about your circle progress bar
OR
as per @pskink comment you can set statically image for those divider.

Comment: if you want to do that in code then see the link in the above comment by Arbaz.in

Comment: I tried but without success making it circle