# Custom Seek bar gets non highlight when touch outtside in its padding area

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I have created custom seekbar to make it work according to my need. There are two questions related to it.

Before it let me show you my code for seekbar

**In android xml**

```
<com.abc.projectname.customlayout.CustomHorizontalSeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:max="7650"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"  // Padding given to show thumbnail properly
                    android:paddingRight="30dp"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:tag="drawable/seek_bar_layout_two"
                    android:thumb="@drawable/dial" />
```

`CustomHorizontalSeekBar` Is a class which I have created to get the tag from seekbar and set progress drawable value as whatever tag have supplied to support multiple theme

**seek_bar_layout_two xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/deselect">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+android:id/progress"
        android:top="20dp"
        android:bottom="20dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/lt_grey_seek_bar">
    </item>
    <!-- android:drawable="@drawable/loadingbar"> -->

</layer-list>
```

Here deselect is and highlighted image which I want to show as background of seekbar permanently.

**lt_grey_seek_bar xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="left" >

    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/lt_grey_border" />

        <gradient
            android:endColor="@color/lt_grey_end"
            android:startColor="@color/lt_grey_start" />
    </shape>

</clip>

Questions
```

1) Can I give same background image for custom seekbar for enable and disable state? If yes than how? It is a special need from my client and it is not necessary to show disable state.

What I have tried:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/seek_bar_layout_two xml" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/seek_bar_layout_two xml" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/seek_bar_layout_two xml" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/seek_bar_layout_two xml"/>
</selector>
```

But Still no success.

2) As you can see in my seekbar implementation I have given padding to show proper thumbnail. But when I click outside the drawn state of seekbar where this padding is available seekbar automatically turns into non highlighted form. How should I stop it?

[Seekbar and its touch area by which it gets non highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MySDh.jpg)

[Non highlight seekbar look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXDgO.jpg)

I have been trying lots of ways to make it work successfully but unable to do so. Can anyone provide me a solution.

This is what I have done in my custom seekbar class

```
Rect bounds = getProgressDrawable().getBounds();
setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(idByTag));
getProgressDrawable().setBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: you dont need any custom `SeekBar`, what you need instead is a custom progress `Drawable` (android:progressDrawable), set it via `setProgressDrawable(Drawable d)`

Comment: Yes I did it in the customseekbar class already but still no progress

Comment: `you dont need any custom SeekBar`

Comment: Could you please explain why I do not need any custom seekbar? Also check my updated question

Comment: so how does the source of  `CustomHorizontalSeekBar` look like?

Comment: That I cannot show(Due to some legal issues) but simple concept is I have extracted Id from whatever tag I am passing in xml and than getting drawable from that id and setting into progressdrawable of seekbar which I have added into question

Comment: so as i said you only need a custom progress `Drawable` class, thats all

Comment: Could you please express your thoughts in form of words. I am unable to understand your perspective

Comment: just try something like this `class MyDrawable extends Drawable { ...` and do your custom drawing in `draw` method

Comment: Please check my xml files "seek_bar_layout_two xml " and "lt_grey_seek_bar xml" they are my custom progress drawable. again I am creating custom seekbar to support multiple theme in my own way.

Comment: did you try to create custom `Drawable` class? what problems do you have with it?

Comment: I do not know about custom drawable stuff could you please share you code or something to support your thoughts

Comment: something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21060826/2252830)

Comment: Do you have anything that we can achieve using XML? This is pro-grammatically and I do not want to achieve it like this according to current implementation.