# Create a gradient progress bar in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, progress-bar, android-seekbar

I am trying to create a progress/indicator style bar for a small android application whereby i am able to define the progress of the bar and only that amount is visible/lit up.
I would like it in a similar style to the below image but in the vertical direction. I have tried using progress bars and seek bars, however I cannot achieve the desired gradient. 
Any help on achieving a solution to the below image or for creating the gradient in the progress/seek bars would be very much appreciated!!

[Progress Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqXb8.jpg)

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21060826/2252830), all you need is to implement different colors for each segment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this , and modify based in your case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="#FF000000"
    android:gradientRadius="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    />
</shape>
```

and in the progress bar add this

```
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_gradient"
```

hope this help